# HashMap Implemention in Java

Tags: java, hash-map, hashcode

I just finished implementing a HashMap in Java, with methods:

- `add(String key, Integer value)`
- `get(String key)`
- `remove(String key)`
- `printHashMap()`

Is this the correct way to implement a `HashMap`? I am implementing a load factor feature that automatically increases the size of the `HashMap` until the load factor is satisfied.

**Bucket.java**

```
public class Bucket {
    // Each Entry contains a key-value pair
    String key;
    Integer value;
    Bucket next; // Used for chaining

    public Bucket(String key, Integer value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**HashMap.java**

```
/*
 * Author: Henry Zhu
 * Building a HashMap that resizes based on load factor
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HashMap {
    private ArrayList<Bucket> data;
    private double loadFactor = 0.75;
    private int initialCapacity = 16;
    private int numBuckets = 0;

    public HashMap() {
        this.data = new ArrayList<Bucket>();

        // Fill the list up to the initial capacity
        for (int i = 0; i < initialCapacity; i++) {
            this.data.add(null);
        }
    }

    public void remove(String key) {
        /*
         * get hash code of key
         * index is hash code % list's size
         * let head be the bucket @ the index
         * let previous be null
         * while the head is not null:
         *     if the head's key = key of bucket we want to delete:
         *         Case 1 (B1 -> B2 (to delete) -> B3):
         *         previous = B1, so set B1.next = B3
         *         end result: B1 -> B3
         *         Case 2 (B1 -> B2 (to delete) -> null):
         *         previous = B1, so set B1.next = null
         *         Case 3 (B1 (to delete) -> B2):
         *         previous = null, set list[index] = B2
         *         Case 4 (B1 (to delete) -> null):
         *         set list[index] = null;
         *         
         *         return
         *     else:
         *         previous becomes head
         *         head becomes head.next
         */
        int hashCode = Math.abs(key.hashCode());
        int index = hashCode % this.data.size();

        Bucket head = this.data.get(index);
        Bucket previous = null;
        while (head != null) {
            if (head.key.equals(key)) { // Evaluates Cases 1 and 2
                if (previous != null) {
                    if (head.next != null) { // Case 1
                        previous.next = head.next;
                    } else { // Case 2
                        previous.next = null;
                    }
                } else { // Evaluates Case 3 and 4
                    if (head.next != null) { // Case 3
                        this.data.set(index, head.next);
                    } else { // Case 4
                        this.data.set(index, null); 
                    }
                }

                numBuckets--;

                return;
            } else {
                previous = head;
                head = head.next;
            }
        }
    }

    public Integer get(String key) {
        /*
         * get the hash code of the key
         * index is the hash code % list's size
         * begin the search:
         *     let head = the bucket at the index
         *     while the head i snot null:
         *         if the head's key = the key we're looking for:
         *             return head.value
         *         if not?
         *             head becomes head.next
         * return -1
         */
        int hashCode = Math.abs(key.hashCode());
        int index = hashCode % this.data.size();

        Bucket head = this.data.get(index);
        while (head != null) {
            if (head.key.equals(key)) {
                return head.value;
            } else {
                head = head.next;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public void add(String key, Integer value) {
        /*
         * get hash code of the key
         * index is hash code % list's size
         * check if key already exists
         *     if key exists: update the bucket
         *     if key doesn't exist:
         *         if index is already occupied: use chaining
         *         if index isn't already occupied, place the bucket at the index
         */
        int hashCode = Math.abs(key.hashCode());
        int index = hashCode % this.data.size();

        Bucket bucket = this.data.get(index);

        boolean alreadyExists = false;

        // See if the key already exists in the HashMap
        for (int i = 0; i < this.data.size(); i++) {
            if (this.data.get(i) != null && this.data.get(i).key.equals(key)) {
                this.data.set(i, new Bucket(key, value));
                alreadyExists = true;
            }
        }

        if (!alreadyExists) {
            // If the spot is occupied, implement the chaining algorithm (uses a LinkedList)
            if (this.data.get(index) != null) {
                Bucket head = this.data.get(index);
                Bucket previous = head;

                while (head != null) {
                    previous = head;
                    head = head.next;
                }

                previous.next = new Bucket(key, value);
            }
            else {
                bucket = new Bucket(key, value);
                this.data.set(index, bucket);
            }
        }

        // Check to see if the capacity of the list needs to be increased.
        numBuckets++;

        if (new Double((1.0 * numBuckets) / this.data.size()).compareTo(loadFactor) >= 0) {
            while (new Double((1.0 * numBuckets) / this.data.size()).compareTo(loadFactor) >= 0) {
                // Increase the size of the list until the load factor is satisfied
                this.data.add(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printMap() {
        /*
         * Go through every element in the list
         * if element is null:
         *    print null
         * if element is a bucket:
         *    set head to equal the element
         *    while the head is not null:
         *       print the head's value
         *       if head.next is not null
         *           print "-> " 
         *       set head = head.next
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < this.data.size(); i++) {
            if (this.data.get(i) == null) {
                System.out.println("[" + i + "] = null");
            } else {
                Bucket head = this.data.get(i);

                String text = "[" + i + "] = ";

                while (head != null) {
                    text += ("(" + head.key + ", " + head.value + ")");

                    if (head.next != null) {
                        text += " -> ";
                    }

                    head = head.next;
                }

                System.out.println(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct way to implement a HashMap?

There are multiple ways to write them.  Did you look any up?

Your cardinal sin is not writing tests to verify that the code works.  And it looks like there's a serious issue here - any reasonably thorough testing should reveal it.